# Circuit to get a short at 0 volts and open at 3.3/5 volts using transistors

Tags: transistors, switches, switching

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxfkOI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the situation I am trying to solve. I am considering using a transistor, but am not 100% sure.

When I get a 0 volt input, the output needs to be a short circuit. When I get a high voltage input (i.e. 3.3 or 5 volts) the output should be an open circuit.

I can do this using an inverter and voltage controlled switch, but how can I do this with transistors? The csv voltage source is a pulse signal. Normally at 0 V, but will turn on momentarily.

Comment: Sounds like a normally closed relay.

Comment: Draw a schematic of the circuit you are considering. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. We'll help you fix it up afterwards.

Comment: @transistor Okay I think I did it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That sounds like a good idea. Can you do this with a transistor though?

Comment: Be sure to specify the voltage to be switched and how much current will pass through the switch. A true, ideal short circuit is not possible in practice. What's the maximum resistance you can accept when the "switch" is conducting?

Comment: Your schematic indicates that the control signal is isolated from the switched terminals. Is that a requirement?

Comment: @elliotalderson If I understand, that is a voltage controlled switch

Comment: There is no ideal "voltage controlled switch" in the real world. You need to specify how much current and voltage the real switch will see, and the maximum voltage you can accept when the switch is conducting. If you require that the control signal be isolated from the switch terminals then the real world design is more complicated.

Comment: Is that switch a 1P3T switch? I think you're trying to demonstrate a push button instead?

Comment: @KingDuken My 2nd paragraph is the most important part of my question. The schematic is just my attempt at clarifying in case my question in text isn't clear

Comment: You cannot design anything perfectly unless it meets spec. BTW what are yours? Including peak current, rms power and load impedance R+X.   So only you can validate the answers with a better spec in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use an opto-MOS SSR, such as **[this](http://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/CPC1117N.pdf/$file/CPC1117N.pdf)** one (CPC1117N):

[image]

It takes a mA or two to turn the output transistors off, so a 1K series resistor on the control input will be suitable for limiting the current (for either 3.3 or 5V).

This particular one can handle 100 or 150mA continuous, but there are others that can handle more current.

Answer (score 0):

You said open and short output, implying isolated outputs, which would be best implemented with a Normally Closed relay. However, if you mean the output is at nearly 0v (technically up to Vce(sat) depending on the collector current) with 0v input, and the output is high impedance (open) when the input signal is high, this can be accomplished with a pair of NPN BJT transistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1jDPs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: But the output will **not** be at zero volts if there is any current flowing, it will be the saturation voltage of the transistor.

Comment: Of course there will be voltage drop in the real world, however, the OP was asking for SHORT and OPEN, not zero volts.

Comment: Elliot, my bad, you were technically correct, I clarified my description to reflect Vbe(sat).

Comment: Yes, the OP was not very clear and the question title was a little different from the body of the question. I think you mean Vce(sat) rather than Vbe(sat), by the way.

Comment: LOL...yes. Thank you for correcting the correction. Should be Vce(sat), not Vbe(sat).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: P-channel JFET, at 0 V between gate and drain channel is fully conductive, increasing positive voltage at gate also increase channel resistance (so called off-state).

[image]

More on this topic [here](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/P-channel-JFET). Example (and cheap) part is 2N3820.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need isolation between in and out:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdbJGG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This cicuit would need V(IN) < 0 to put M1 in a conducting state.